# Syncing x-axis in matplotlib subplots using sharex

Tags: python, mongodb, matplotlib, charts

I have just started coding in Python and am currently working on financial data in association with charting using matplotlib, data analysis using pandas and database as in MongoDB. This might be a basic question however with all answers I have gone through, I have not found a solution.

My dataset is in the form of a dataframe:

Index | Close | Date | High | Low | Open | Volume |

0 | 1259.95 | 2015-02-02 | 1295.00 | 1256.00 | 1280.00 | 59400 |

1 | 1264.15 | 2015-02-03 | 1280.00 | 1255.65 | 1264.00 | 43100 |

2 | 1267.85 | 2015-02-04 | 1288.95 | 1263.10 | 1273.20 | 41500 |

Codeblock:

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.finance import candlestick, volume_overlay
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from feed.get_data import get_ticker_data #simply gets data from yahoo into dataframe

    def candlestick_data_1(ticker, startdate, enddate):
    data = get_ticker_data(ticker, 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', startdate=startdate, enddate=enddate)
    print data
    data['Date'] = mdates.date2num(pd.to_datetime(data['Date']))
    dataAr = [tuple(x) for x in data[['Date', 'Open', 'Close', 'High', 'Low']].to_records(index=False)]
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax1 = plt.subplot(211)
    ax2 = plt.subplot(212)
    candlestick(ax1, dataAr, colorup='#00ff00', alpha=1.0)
    volume_overlay(ax2, data['Open'], data['Close'], data['Volume'])
    plt.show()
```

When I am not using 'sharex' the figure plots well however x-axis are not in sync as shown below:

[candlestick chart using matplotlib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXJ8n.png)

When I am however using sharex, the chart gets completely distorted:
Codeblock:

```
ax2 = plt.subplot(212, sharex=ax1)
```

[chart distortion using sharex to share axes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARc4l.png)

Comment: Your lower graph runs from -5 to 20. Your upper graph runs from 735630 to 735660. Now, if you want them to share the same axis, this axis needs to run from -5 to 735660. The respective range of data of 25 or 3 units within an axis of length 735665 is clearly not obervable. So if you want both datasets to share the same axis you need to first think about what they have in common and adapt the data accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. x-axis in both cases are dates actually, though I have not converted them into dates and left them as floats. Even in that case as it is a dataframe object, y-axis limits for both are different which is fine. X-axis datapoints are exactly common and in fact the same. (And they are dates - float equivalent is always positive)